# If formula and or formula don't show expected result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use `IF` and `OR` together. Both of the `OR` statements are true (I checked them separately and it works). Combined together the `IF` statements show `FALSE`, although both of them are `TRUE`, and also if only one was `TRUE` it should've returned `TRUE`.
data:

[image]

ref table:

[image]

```
IF(OR(B2072=VLOOKUP(B2072,'Ref table'!AA3:$AB$20,1,0), C2072=SEARCH("administrativ*",C2072)), "other")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and show the data you are testing with this formula, the formula results and the separate function calls evaluating to true.

Comment: Is the name of the sheet you are referencing in the VLOOKUP actually called 'Ref table' ?

Comment: I think part of your problem is that vlookup result is `#N/A`. However, this should have made your whole formula to be `#N/A`.

Comment: Hi @litalr ,, your formula has few crucial mistakes,,, like `C2072=SEARCH(` is wrong syntax,,,, and OR doesn't required,,, better try this one `=IFERROR(IF(K51=VLOOKUP(K51,RefTab!M$51:N$53,1,TRUE),SEARCH("Assi*",N51),"Other Name"),"")` ☺

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:  what you describe CAN'T happen.

You say the result is `FALSE` which REQUIRES each of the `OR()`'s to be `FALSE`:  NOT errors, but actual `FALSE` results. Yet they neither of them can ever be `FALSE`. They both can either be `TRUE` or be an error.

Specifically, the second condition can almost never be true because `SEARCH()` returns a number (the position the found string begins) so to EVER be `TRUE`, the cell would have to contain only numerals, yet the search can only give a non-error result if it has that text in it. Ergo, it can NEVER be `TRUE` as used and therefore will always give an error, not a `FALSE`. `OR()` returns an error in that case, not a `FALSE` (indeed, simply setting that portion to an "=" as a standalone formula does the same), so you could never have gotten `TRUE` from that half, even though you say you do in your post.

So something important must be missing, or wrong. Without more, or accurate information, no one here can help you.

Same, by the way, with the first half:  it either returns `TRUE` (which it can, as used here, unlike the second half), or it returns an error. But never a `FALSE`, so as long as it is `TRUE`, it is not the problem. Not true? Well, an error is an error and the `IF()` will return an error, NOT a `FALSE`.

Folks want to help you, so consider your information and try to see where it's wrong or incomplete. For example, one figures the two conditions really do produce `FALSE`'s as standalong things, so what's different in the post from the actual spreadsheet? That's a good starting point.

And either way, that second condition simply HAS to be different than posted. As used here, it can never give anything but an error not a `FALSE` (it could give that in other conditions, but not in these). So looking at that is a good idea. Then folks can help. They do want to.